# document.getElementById() equivalent in React 2020

Tags: reactjs, getelementbyid, use-ref

I have a component called Button.js that has a button that when clicked i simply would like to know if i am accessing the a div in another component called Timer.js. In vanilla javascript i would simply use document.getElementById() to capture the DOM node. How is this done in React?

I came across callback-refs in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) but it isn't working. If using a ref isn't the React way of accessing DOM elements please refer me to the best way to do this. thanks in advance.

Button.js

```
    function Button() {
    const getHtml = () => {
        const node = test.current;
        console.log(node);
    }
return (
         <button onClick={getHtml}>GetHtml</button>
       )
}
```

Timer.js

```
function Timer() {
  const test = useRef(null);
  return (
   <div ref={test}>... </div>
   <Button />
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use a reference to check if a component is rendered inside of another one.
You could get what you're looking for with `createContext` and `useContext`.

(It could work like you tried it. If you'd pass the ref to the button as a prop.)

With the context: You create a `TimerContext.Provider` in your Timer component and in your button you can check with `useContext(TimerContext)` if the expected key is in the object. If it's not there then the button is not inside of your Timer.

Please have a look at the snippet below or in the following [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-fire-fiuxk).

```js
//import React, { useContext, createContext } from "react";
//import "./styles.css";

const { useContext, createContext } = React;

const ContainerContext = createContext({
  isInContainer: null
});

const Container = () => {
  return (
    <ContainerContext.Provider value={{ isInContainer: true }}>
      <p>
        In container:
        <Button />
      </p>
    </ContainerContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Button = () => {
  const { isInContainer } = useContext(ContainerContext);
  console.log(isInContainer);
  const isInside = () => {
    alert(isInContainer ? "clicked inside" : "not in container");
  };

  return <button onClick={isInside}>Click me</button>;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container />
      <Button />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Update 15.04.2020**

The question was not clear to me at first but now I understand the use-case. The idea is to have an `Editor` component where you're writing markup that can be used to generate a copied snippet view and/or a html markup output.

For this the best is to use a reference to the `Editor` component and pass it as prop to the preview/output component - it would be also possible with a context but passing it is easier.

Like in the following [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-lederberg-ss721).

Comment: I have two components in different js files Timer.js and Button.js. When I use your code ContainerContext is undefined in Button.js because it doesn't know it's defined in Timer.js.

Comment: you can `export const ContainerContext = ...` and do `import {ContainerContext} from './Timer'` in Button.js

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's still not working. I'm perplexed as to why React has made  something so simple in vanilla javascript so difficult. document.getElementById().

Comment: if you have your code in a Github repo, I could have a look.

Comment: Thank you. I've created a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-turing-yxx6j

Comment: So what should happen if the user clicks on `get HTML`? You want to get the html markup of the editor, right? Do you want to have it displayed as a modal?

Comment: When a user clicks get HTML I would like the html markup from the div in Editor.js with a className "editor" to append to the div with a className "getcontent" which is in Buttons.js

Comment: So in the following [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-lederberg-ss721) I've added the feature. I think it's the best to pass a reference to the buttons and then you can work with the content of the editor. Now it's more clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks it works! Question. I noticed in Editor.js you used the editorRef on the button component as well as the div. I decided to remove it from the button component and it stop working. why is the ref required on both?

Comment: On the editor div `ref={editorRef}` is setting the reference. This could be also written like `ref={ref => editorRef.current=ref}` and the `editorRef={editorRef}` is passing the reference as a prop to the button component - so you can access it inside your button component.

Comment: I know it's been a week since you help me with this question. But if you don't mind I have a hypothetical question I wanted to pick your brain on. If I wanted to for whatever reason create another component home.js which also imported the button component button.js, how would i access 'editorRef' in Editor.js? https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-sun-xn7q7?file=/src/Home.js

Comment: Sure, no problem. You could do it with a `useEditor` hook or context. For `useEditor` have a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-shadow-npdb1) and here for the [context example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-http-44h1s?file=/src/App.js). Both would work but I'd prefer the context approach - it's more React-like and easier to read IMO. The trick is to have one `editorRef` (higher in the component tree) that can be set from the `Editor` component with a context method.